# Android notification icon to change background according to status bar color

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am making an app, which displays a notification when a certain task is completed. This is my code:

```
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 4024;

NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText("Text")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
    .setLights(Color.GREEN, 1000, 1000)
    .setVibrate(new long[] {500, 500, 500, 500, 500})
    .setAutoCancel(true);

Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
      resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

And this is my icon (from https://material.io/icons/#ic_signal_cellular_4_bar):

[image: https://material.io/icons/#ic_signal_cellular_4_bar]

When running this the icon displays fine, but it doesn't change color according to the background of the status bar, like for example whatsapp's icon does:

[image: I know de way]
[image: Do you know de way]

So my question is how I can make it change color according to the background.

EDIT:

Also when using the white icon it doesn't change color.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html):

> Status bar icons are composed simply of white pixels on a transparent backdrop, with alpha blending used for smooth edges and internal texture where appropriate.

Your icon would appear to be using black pixels. Try downloading the white edition of that icon, and see if you have better luck.

Comment: I tried, sadly it didn't work, now the icon stays white all the time.

Comment: @ConnerDassen: Try using the Image Asset Wizard in Android Studio, set to make "Notification Icons", and choose the 4-bar cellular signal icon from the clip art.